# Eclipse Plugin extension point org.eclipse.ui.command: how to change text?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

EDIT: Here is the full plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>

<plugin>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <category
            name="TB Category"
            id="TBPlugin.commands.category">
      </category>
      <command
            name="fubar1"
            categoryId="TBPlugin.commands.category"
            id="TBPlugin.commands.sampleCommand">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
            commandId="TBPlugin.commands.sampleCommand"
            class="tbplugin.handlers.SampleHandler">
      </handler>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
      <key
            commandId="TBPlugin.commands.sampleCommand"
            contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
            sequence="M1+6"
            schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration">
      </key>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
         <menu
               label="TB"
               mnemonic="M"
               id="TBPlugin.menus.sampleMenu">
            <command
                  commandId="TBPlugin.commands.sampleCommand"
                  mnemonic="S"
                  id="TBPlugin.menus.sampleCommand">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions">
         <toolbar
               id="TBPlugin.toolbars.sampleToolbar">
            <command
                  commandId="TBPlugin.commands.sampleCommand"
                  icon="icons/sample.png"
                  tooltip="TB"
                  id="TBPlugin.toolbars.sampleCommand">
            </command>
         </toolbar>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

I would expect that fubar would show up someplace but I see "Sample Command" when, for example, I click on the new item in the menu bar, not "fubar". Moreover, search the code, xml files, etc. and the specific string "Sample Command" is not showing up. Where is that string defined and how do I change it?

Comment: Testing here this plugin.xml creates a menu 'TB' in the main menu with a single menu item labeled 'fubar1'.  Please make sure the Run Configuration you are using specifies `-clean` in the 'Program Arguments' section of the 'Arguments' tab and doesn't include other plugins which might cause confusion (and that you are running the correct Run Configuration)

Comment: thanks very much for testing this. i will investigate as you suggest although clean i am sure is there.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` value in the command is the default name of the command. It may be overridden by the menu definition.

If the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point is used to define the menu you might have something like:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="some location URI">
     <command
           commandId="TBPlugin.commands.sampleCommand"
           label="%command.name"
           style="push">
```

`label` sets the displayed name, it is optional with the command name being the default.

If `label` starts with `%` it is the id of a property in the plugin's bundle localization properties file (usually `plugin.properties` or `OSGI-INF/i10n/bundle.properties`)

Comment: So sampleCommand becomes "Sample Command"? Also, although I can't see how it would work but is there some sort of caching so that changes to plugin.xml are not immediately visible? I run the test version of Eclipse from Eclipse itself so i don't know where any information would be cached but it seems like I am observing caching.

Comment: btw, i stop and restart the test version of eclipse -- i would not expect changes to show up at all until that happened.

Comment: There is caching but when Eclipse creates the Run Configuration for testing it normally adds the `-clean` Argument which clears the caches. Check your Run Configuration.

Comment: clean was not there but even after added i am not seeing changes. using Oxygen if that matters.

Comment: Actually I don't understand what changes you are talking about. My answer is just talking about things that would already be in the code somewhere.

Comment: 1. I change plugin.xml and then rerun test version of Eclipse from Eclipse but do not see label changes, etc. 2. I changed run config to have -clean switch and i still did not see changes after multiple runs

Comment: Change what in the plugin.xml? If the menu is displaying as 'Sample Command' there must already be a menu definition somewhere doing that just adding this code won't change that - and you need to at least change the `locationURI` to see it at all.

Comment: where besides plugin.xml is that menu definition? note that this started out as a Hello World which I made no changes to besides Java code.

Comment: Edit your question and add the plugin.xml